# Front-end proxy with Nginx to locahost returns 502 bad gateway error

Tags: nginx, proxy

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ ls /etc/nginx
conf.d          koi-win            nginx.conf       sites-enabled  win-utf
fastcgi.conf    mime.types         proxy_params     snippets
fastcgi_params  modules-available  scgi_params      ssl
koi-utf         modules-enabled    sites-available  uwsgi_params
```

Here is my sites-enabled/local.lawnhero.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .local.lawnhero.com;
    root "/home/vagrant/code/lawnhero/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;



    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:8000";
    }



    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/local.lawnhero.com-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/local.lawnhero.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/local.lawnhero.com.key;
}
```

I'm attemping to use a front-end js framework called Quasar(localhost:8000) and use it with laravel 5.8 backend which is (local.lawnhero.com)

Sometimes quasar dev will open the dev-server at http://localhost:8001

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 7917ms                                                                                                                                                            9:35:27 AM


 N  App dir........... /home/mirage/code/quasar
    App URL........... http://localhost:8001
    Dev mode.......... spa
    Pkg quasar........ v1.1.0
    Pkg @quasar/app... v1.0.6

 app:dev-server Opening default browser at http://localhost:8001 +8s
```

This is the first time i've tried to set up a proxy and i've been trying to troubleshoot for days. Please help lol.

webserver's error log:

```
2019/09/04 13:50:36 [error] 10716#10716: *38 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: local.lawnhero.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/", host: "local.lawnhero.com"
```

Comment: It won't work if nginx tries to connect to port 8000 and your app is listening on port 8001. The first thing you need to do is to get Quasar to listen on the right host/port.

Comment: From your config :proxy_pass "http://localhost:8000"; So you need your application to listen on the 8000 port on the machine, else connection will drop

Comment: @logal correct, you hit 8000 instead 8001 - okay i am lame only the third :(